# SQLInner Join For large Records

Tags: mysql

I have two table of  130,897 rows and i want inner join both tables in my localhost. It takes so much of time or some times it exceeds the execution time . Can Some tell me How to optimize the query? 
Thanks In advance

Comment: Please provide information about table schema, indexes, the actual query, etc.

Comment: There is no Primary key in both tables , Every Column in both table  are Varchar() Datataype

Comment: Well, here's your answer - without indexes it will be slow - add an index on the joining columns.